# pandas read_csv error when reading csv-file with backslashes in the file

Tags: pandas, csv, unicode, backslash

Error when reading a file containing backslashes

I have a csv-file with inside the rows string including "\" and "\\" inside the strings
If i use pandas read_csv it is giving an error even with the right encoding.
Even with various encodings i get different errors but none of them works. Only when i replace the backslash by another character it works.

any ideas?

Kind regards,

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\testfile.csv',encoding="unicode_escape")
print(df.head())
```

Testfile:

```
Source chart;Chart element;Element comment;Block type;Destination chart;Chart element;Element comment;Block type;
"@CPU_RT";"@CPU_RT.CPU_RT_DATA";"";"CPU_RT";"@(1)";"AS_1.CPU_RT_DATA";"";"OB_BEGIN";
"@(1)";"AS_1.CPU_DIAG";"";"OB_BEGIN";"@(2)";"AS_2.CPU_DIAG";"";"OB_END";
"@(1)";"AS_1.EN_SUB0";"Enable Subnet 0";"OB_BEGIN";"@(3)";"CPU_410-5H_1.EN";"";"SUBNET";
"@(1)";"AS_1.CPU_DIAG";"";"OB_BEGIN";"@(3)";"CPU_410-5H_1.CPU_DIAG";"";"SUBNET";
"@(1)";"AS_1.CPU_OB_5X";"";"OB_BEGIN";"@(3)";"CPU_410-5H_1.CPU_OB_5X";"";"SUBNET";
"@(1)";"AS_1.SZL_71";"";"OB_BEGIN";"@(3)";"CPU_410-5H_1.SZL_71";"";"SUBNET";
"@(5)";"UR2ALU_1.OUT";"";"AND";"@(4)";"UR2ALU_1.EN";"";"RACK";
"@(1)";"AS_1.CPU_DIAG";"";"OB_BEGIN";"@(4)";"UR2ALU_1.CPU_DIAG";"";"RACK";
"@(3)";"CPU_410-5H_1.SUB_DIAG";"";"SUBNET";"@(4)";"UR2ALU_1.SUB_DIAG";"";"RACK";
"@(3)";"CPU_410-5H_1.EN_R0";"Enable Rack 0";"SUBNET";"@(5)";"UR2ALU_1.IN1";"";"AND";
"@(1)";"AS_1.EN_SUB0";"Enable Subnet 0";"OB_BEGIN";"@(5)";"UR2ALU_1.IN2";"";"AND";
"@(1)";"AS_1.CPU_DIAG";"";"OB_BEGIN";"@(6)";"CP_443-1_1.CPU_DIAG";"";"MOD_CENTRAL";
"@(4)";"UR2ALU_1.RAC_DIAG";"";"RACK";"@(6)";"CP_443-1_1.RAC_DIAG";"";"MOD_CENTRAL";
"@(7)";"PS_405_10A_1.OUT";"";"AND";"@(6)";"PS_405_10A_1.EN";"";"PS";
"@(1)";"AS_1.CPU_DIAG";"";"OB_BEGIN";"@(6)";"PS_405_10A_1.CPU_DIAG";"";"PS";
"@(4)";"UR2ALU_1.RAC_DIAG";"";"RACK";"@(6)";"PS_405_10A_1.RAC_DIAG";"";"PS";
"@(5)";"UR2ALU_1.OUT";"";"AND";"@(7)";"PS_405_10A_1.IN1";"";"AND";
"@(4)";"UR2ALU_1.EN_M0";"Enable MODUL 0";"RACK";"@(7)";"PS_405_10A_1.IN2";"";"AND";
"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\Pomp_CCM";"CCM.AutAct";"";"CCM";"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\CCM1_EMT";"Test_CCM_EMT.CCM_AutAct";"";"Test_CCM_EMT";
"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\Pomp_CCM";"CCM.Cmd1Act";"";"CCM";"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\CCM1_EMT";"Test_CCM_EMT.CCM_Cmd1Act";"";"Test_CCM_EMT";
"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\Pomp_CCM";"CCM.Cmd2Act";"";"CCM";"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\CCM1_EMT";"Test_CCM_EMT.CCM_Cmd2Act";"";"Test_CCM_EMT";
"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\Pomp_CCM";"CCM.Cmd3Act";"";"CCM";"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\CCM1_EMT";"Test_CCM_EMT.CCM_Cmd3Act";"";"Test_CCM_EMT";
"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\Pomp_CCM";"CCM.Cmd4Act";"";"CCM";"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\CCM1_EMT";"Test_CCM_EMT.CCM_Cmd4Act";"";"Test_CCM_EMT";
"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\Pomp_CCM";"CCM.Cmd5Act";"";"CCM";"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\CCM1_EMT";"Test_CCM_EMT.CCM_Cmd5Act";"";"Test_CCM_EMT";
"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\Pomp_CCM";"CCM.LockAct";"";"CCM";"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\CCM1_EMT";"Test_CCM_EMT.CCM_LockAct";"";"Test_CCM_EMT";
"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\CCM\\CCM1_EPHT";"CCM_EPHT.CMD_Q";"Active Setpoint";"CCM_EPHT";"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\CCM\\CCM1_EPHT";"CCM_EPHT.CMD_AI";"Actual Value Input";"CCM_EPHT";
"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\CCM1_EMT";"Test_CCM_EMT.QAUTMAN";"Current operating mode";"Test_CCM_EMT";"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\CCM\\CCM1_EPHT";"CCM_EPHT.CCM_EMT_QAUTMAN";"Current operating mode";"CCM_EPHT";
"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\CCM1_EMT";"Test_CCM_EMT.IDLE";""Idle" operating state";"Test_CCM_EMT";"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\CCM\\CCM1_EPHT";"CCM_EPHT.CCM_EMT_IDLE";""Idle" operating state";"CCM_EPHT";
"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\CCM1_EMT";"Test_CCM_EMT.STARTING";""Starting" operating state";"Test_CCM_EMT";"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\CCM\\CCM1_EPHT";"CCM_EPHT.CCM_EMT_STARTING";""Starting" operating state";"CCM_EPHT";
"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\CCM1_EMT";"Test_CCM_EMT.RUN";""Run" operating state";"Test_CCM_EMT";"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\CCM\\CCM1_EPHT";"CCM_EPHT.CCM_EMT_RUN";""Run" operating state";"CCM_EPHT";
"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\CCM1_EMT";"Test_CCM_EMT.READY_TC";""Ready to complete" state";"Test_CCM_EMT";"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\CCM\\CCM1_EPHT";"CCM_EPHT.CCM_EMT_READY_TC";""Ready to complete" state";"CCM_EPHT";
"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\CCM1_EMT";"Test_CCM_EMT.COMPLETING";""Completing" operating state";"Test_CCM_EMT";"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\CCM\\CCM1_EPHT";"CCM_EPHT.CCM_EMT_COMPLETING";""Completing" operating state";"CCM_EPHT";
"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\CCM1_EMT";"Test_CCM_EMT.ERROR_COMPLETING";""Error completing" operating state";"Test_CCM_EMT";"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\CCM\\CCM1_EPHT";"CCM_EPHT.CCM_EMT_ERROR_COMPLETING";""Error completing" operating state";"CCM_EPHT";
"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\CCM1_EMT";"Test_CCM_EMT.COMPLETED";""Completed" operating state";"Test_CCM_EMT";"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\CCM\\CCM1_EPHT";"CCM_EPHT.CCM_EMT_COMPLETED";""Completed" operating state";"CCM_EPHT";
"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\CCM1_EMT";"Test_CCM_EMT.HOLDING";""Holding" operating state";"Test_CCM_EMT";"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\CCM\\CCM1_EPHT";"CCM_EPHT.CCM_EMT_HOLDING";""Holding" operating state";"CCM_EPHT";
"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\CCM1_EMT";"Test_CCM_EMT.HELD";""Held" operating state";"Test_CCM_EMT";"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\CCM\\CCM1_EPHT";"CCM_EPHT.CCM_EMT_HELD";""Held" operating state";"CCM_EPHT";
"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\CCM1_EMT";"Test_CCM_EMT.RESUMING";""Resuming" operating state";"Test_CCM_EMT";"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\CCM\\CCM1_EPHT";"CCM_EPHT.CCM_EMT_RESUMING";""Resuming" operating state";"CCM_EPHT";
"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\CCM1_EMT";"Test_CCM_EMT.ERROR";""Error" operating state";"Test_CCM_EMT";"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\CCM\\CCM1_EPHT";"CCM_EPHT.CCM_EMT_ERROR";""Error" operating state";"CCM_EPHT";
"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\CCM1_EMT";"Test_CCM_EMT.HELD_ERROR";""Held error" operating state";"Test_CCM_EMT";"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\CCM\\CCM1_EPHT";"CCM_EPHT.CCM_EMT_HELD_ERROR";""Held error" operating state";"CCM_EPHT";
"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\CCM1_EMT";"Test_CCM_EMT.RESU_ERROR";""Resuming error" operating state";"Test_CCM_EMT";"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\CCM\\CCM1_EPHT";"CCM_EPHT.CCM_EMT_RESU_ERROR";""Resuming error" operating state";"CCM_EPHT";
"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\CCM1_EMT";"Test_CCM_EMT.ABORTING";""Aborting" operating state";"Test_CCM_EMT";"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\CCM\\CCM1_EPHT";"CCM_EPHT.CCM_EMT_ABORTING";""Aborting" operating state";"CCM_EPHT";
"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\CCM1_EMT";"Test_CCM_EMT.ABORTED";""Aborted" operating state";"Test_CCM_EMT";"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\CCM\\CCM1_EPHT";"CCM_EPHT.CCM_EMT_ABORTED";""Aborted" operating state";"CCM_EPHT";
"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\CCM1_EMT";"Test_CCM_EMT.STOPPING";""Stopping" operating state";"Test_CCM_EMT";"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\CCM\\CCM1_EPHT";"CCM_EPHT.CCM_EMT_STOPPING";""Stopping" operating state";"CCM_EPHT";
"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\CCM1_EMT";"Test_CCM_EMT.STOPPED";""Stopped" operating state";"Test_CCM_EMT";"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\CCM\\CCM1_EPHT";"CCM_EPHT.CCM_EMT_STOPPED";""Stopped" operating state";"CCM_EPHT";
"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\CCM1_EMT";"Test_CCM_EMT.BUSY";"Status "Busy" (=neither "Idle" nor "Completed" nor "Aborted" nor "Stopped")";"Test_CCM_EMT";"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\CCM\\CCM1_EPHT";"CCM_EPHT.CCM_EMT_BUSY";"Status "Busy" (=neither "Idle" nor "Completed" nor "Aborted" nor "Stopped")";"CCM_EPHT";
"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\CCM1_EMT";"Test_CCM_EMT.ERRG";"Collective error(QEXT_ERR|OP_ERR|LI_ERR|EXEC_ERR)";"Test_CCM_EMT";"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\CCM\\CCM1_EPHT";"CCM_EPHT.CCM_EMT_ERRG";"Collective error(QEXT_ERR|OP_ERR|LI_ERR|EXEC_ERR)";"CCM_EPHT";
"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\CCM1_EMT";"Test_CCM_EMT.QDIS_START";"Disable "Start"";"Test_CCM_EMT";"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\CCM\\CCM1_EPHT";"CCM_EPHT.CCM_EMT_QDIS_START";"Disable "Start"";"CCM_EPHT";
"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\CCM1_EMT";"Test_CCM_EMT.QCONT_T_ERR";"Max. run time for "Continuous mode" exceeded";"Test_CCM_EMT";"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\CCM\\CCM1_EPHT";"CCM_EPHT.CCM_EMT_QCONT_T_ERR";"Max. run time for "Continuous mode" exceeded";"CCM_EPHT";
"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\CCM1_EMT";"Test_CCM_EMT.POSINO";"Position text number";"Test_CCM_EMT";"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\CCM\\CCM1_EPHT";"CCM_EPHT.CCM_EMT_POSINO";"Position text number";"CCM_EPHT";
"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\CCM1_EMT";"Test_CCM_EMT.OPTIPNO";"Information text number for operator";"Test_CCM_EMT";"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\CCM\\CCM1_EPHT";"CCM_EPHT.CCM_EMT_OPTIPNO";"Information text number for operator";"CCM_EPHT";
"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\CCM1_EMT";"Test_CCM_EMT.QCS";"Current control strategy";"Test_CCM_EMT";"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\CCM\\CCM1_EPHT";"CCM_EPHT.CCM_EMT_QCS";"Current control strategy";"CCM_EPHT";
"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\CCM1_EMT";"Test_CCM_EMT.Command_AO";"Actual Value Output";"Test_CCM_EMT";"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\CCM\\CCM1_EPHT";"CCM_EPHT.CCM_EMT_Command_AO";"Actual Value Output";"CCM_EPHT";
"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\Test_CCM\\CCM1_EMT";"Test_CCM_EMT.Command_ERR";"Setpoint Input Error";"Test_CCM_EMT";"Kitchen\Stove_1\Pot_1\CCM\\CCM1_EPHT";"CCM_EPHT.CCM_EMT_Command_ERR";"Setpoint Input Error";"CCM_EPHT";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Turn\\Desk_1_Turn";"De1_Turn.MotRevL_FwdAut";"1=Start: Forward Start Command in Auto Mode";"Turn";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Turn\Mot_Turn\\De1_Mot_Turn";"De1_Mot_Turn.FwdAut";"1=Start: Forward Start Command in Auto Mode";"MotRevL";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Turn\\Desk_1_Turn";"De1_Turn.MotRevL_StopAut";"1=Stop: Stop Command in Auto Mode";"Turn";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Turn\Mot_Turn\\De1_Mot_Turn";"De1_Mot_Turn.StopAut";"1=Stop: Stop Command in Auto Mode";"MotRevL";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Turn\\Desk_1_Turn";"De1_Turn.MotRevL_RevAut";"1=Start: Reverse Start Command in Auto Mode";"Turn";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Turn\Mot_Turn\\De1_Mot_Turn";"De1_Mot_Turn.RevAut";"1=Start: Reverse Start Command in Auto Mode";"MotRevL";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Turn\\Desk_1_Turn";"De1_Turn.MotRevL_ModLiOp";"1=Link/Auto,0=Manual: Input to Auto/Manual Commands";"Turn";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Turn\Mot_Turn\\De1_Mot_Turn";"De1_Mot_Turn.ModLiOp";"1=Link/Auto,0=Manual: Input to Auto/Manual Commands";"MotRevL";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Turn\\Desk_1_Turn";"De1_Turn.MotRevL_AutModLi";"1=Auto Mode: Auto Mode by Linked or SFC";"Turn";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Turn\Mot_Turn\\De1_Mot_Turn";"De1_Mot_Turn.AutModLi";"1=Auto Mode: Auto Mode by Linked or SFC";"MotRevL";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Turn\\Desk_1_Turn";"De1_Turn.MotRevL_RstLi";"Linked Reset Signal";"Turn";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Turn\Mot_Turn\\De1_Mot_Turn";"De1_Mot_Turn.RstLi";"Linked Reset Signal";"MotRevL";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Turn\\Desk_1_Turn";"De1_Turn.QBA_EN";"BATCH enable";"Turn";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Turn\Mot_Turn\\De1_Mot_Turn";"De1_Mot_Turn.BatchEn";"Enable Remote Operation of Controller by Batch Recipe";"MotRevL";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Turn\\Desk_1_Turn";"De1_Turn.QBA_ID";"BATCH charge number";"Turn";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Turn\Mot_Turn\\De1_Mot_Turn";"De1_Mot_Turn.BatchID";"Current Batch ID (number)";"MotRevL";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Turn\\Desk_1_Turn";"De1_Turn.QBA_NA";"BATCH charge name";"Turn";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Turn\Mot_Turn\\De1_Mot_Turn";"De1_Mot_Turn.BatchName";"Current Batch Name";"MotRevL";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Turn\\Desk_1_Turn";"De1_Turn.QSTEP_NO";"BATCH step number 32Bit";"Turn";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Turn\Mot_Turn\\De1_Mot_Turn";"De1_Mot_Turn.StepNo";"Batch Step Number";"MotRevL";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Drain\Val_Drain\\De1_Val_Drain";"De1_Val_Drain.Closed";"1=Valve is Closed";"VlvL";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Drain\Val_Drain\\De1_Val_Drain";"3.In1";"Input 1";"Or04";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Drain\Val_Drain\\De1_Val_Drain";"De1_Val_Drain.Closing";"1=Valve is Closing";"VlvL";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Drain\Val_Drain\\De1_Val_Drain";"3.In2";"Input 2";"Or04";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Drain\Val_Drain\\De1_Val_Drain";"De1_Val_Drain.Opened";"1=Valve is Open";"VlvL";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Drain\Val_Drain\\De1_Val_Drain";"4.In1";"Input 1";"Or04";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Drain\Val_Drain\\De1_Val_Drain";"De1_Val_Drain.Opening";"1=Valve is Opening";"VlvL";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Drain\Val_Drain\\De1_Val_Drain";"4.In2";"Input 2";"Or04";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Drain\\Desk_1_Drain";"De1_Drain.VlvL_OpenAut";"1=Open: Open Command in Auto Mode";"Drain";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Drain\Val_Drain\\De1_Val_Drain";"De1_Val_Drain.OpenAut";"1=Open: Open Command in Auto Mode";"VlvL";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Drain\\Desk_1_Drain";"De1_Drain.VlvL_CloseAut";"1=Close: Close Command in Auto Mode";"Drain";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Drain\Val_Drain\\De1_Val_Drain";"De1_Val_Drain.CloseAut";"1=Close: Close Command in Auto Mode";"VlvL";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Drain\\Desk_1_Drain";"De1_Drain.VlvL_ModLiOp";"1=Link/Auto,0=Manual: Input to auto/manual commands";"Drain";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Drain\Val_Drain\\De1_Val_Drain";"De1_Val_Drain.ModLiOp";"1=Link/Auto,0=Manual: Input to auto/manual commands";"VlvL";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Drain\\Desk_1_Drain";"De1_Drain.VlvL_AutModLi";"1=Auto mode: Auto mode by linked or SFC";"Drain";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Drain\Val_Drain\\De1_Val_Drain";"De1_Val_Drain.AutModLi";"1=Auto mode: Auto mode by linked or SFC";"VlvL";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Drain\Val_Drain\\De1_Val_Drain";"4.Out";"Output";"Or04";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Drain\Val_Drain\\De1_Val_Drain";"De1_Val_Drain.FbkOpen";"1=Open: Feedback of Valve Opened";"VlvL";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Drain\Val_Drain\\De1_Val_Drain";"3.Out";"Output";"Or04";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Drain\Val_Drain\\De1_Val_Drain";"De1_Val_Drain.FbkClose";"1=Close: Feedback of Valve Closed";"VlvL";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Drain\\Desk_1_Drain";"De1_Drain.VlvL_RstLi";"Linked reset signal";"Drain";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Drain\Val_Drain\\De1_Val_Drain";"De1_Val_Drain.RstLi";"Linked reset signal";"VlvL";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Drain\\Desk_1_Drain";"De1_Drain.QBA_EN";"BATCH enable";"Drain";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Drain\Val_Drain\\De1_Val_Drain";"De1_Val_Drain.BatchEn";"Enable remote operation of controller by Batch recipe";"VlvL";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Drain\\Desk_1_Drain";"De1_Drain.QBA_ID";"BATCH charge number";"Drain";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Drain\Val_Drain\\De1_Val_Drain";"De1_Val_Drain.BatchID";"Current Batch ID (number)";"VlvL";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Drain\\Desk_1_Drain";"De1_Drain.QBA_NA";"BATCH charge name";"Drain";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Drain\Val_Drain\\De1_Val_Drain";"De1_Val_Drain.BatchName";"Current Batch name";"VlvL";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Drain\\Desk_1_Drain";"De1_Drain.QSTEP_NO";"BATCH step number 32Bit";"Drain";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Drain\Val_Drain\\De1_Val_Drain";"De1_Val_Drain.StepNo";"Batch step number";"VlvL";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\Val_Oil\\De1_Val_Oil";"De1_Val_Oil.Closed";"1=Valve is Closed";"VlvL";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\Val_Oil\\De1_Val_Oil";"3.In1";"Input 1";"Or04";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\Val_Oil\\De1_Val_Oil";"De1_Val_Oil.Closing";"1=Valve is Closing";"VlvL";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\Val_Oil\\De1_Val_Oil";"3.In2";"Input 2";"Or04";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\Val_Oil\\De1_Val_Oil";"De1_Val_Oil.Opened";"1=Valve is Open";"VlvL";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\Val_Oil\\De1_Val_Oil";"4.In1";"Input 1";"Or04";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\Val_Oil\\De1_Val_Oil";"De1_Val_Oil.Opening";"1=Valve is Opening";"VlvL";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\Val_Oil\\De1_Val_Oil";"4.In2";"Input 2";"Or04";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\\Desk_1_Add_Ingredie";"De1_add_Ingredie.Oel_OpenAut";"1=Open: Open Command in Auto Mode";"Add_Ingredient";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\Val_Oil\\De1_Val_Oil";"De1_Val_Oil.OpenAut";"1=Open: Open Command in Auto Mode";"VlvL";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\\Desk_1_Add_Ingredie";"De1_add_Ingredie.Oel_CloseAut";"1=Close: Close Command in Auto Mode";"Add_Ingredient";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\Val_Oil\\De1_Val_Oil";"De1_Val_Oil.CloseAut";"1=Close: Close Command in Auto Mode";"VlvL";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\\Desk_1_Add_Ingredie";"De1_add_Ingredie.Oel_ModLiOp";"1=Link/Auto,0=Manual: Input to auto/manual commands";"Add_Ingredient";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\Val_Oil\\De1_Val_Oil";"De1_Val_Oil.ModLiOp";"1=Link/Auto,0=Manual: Input to auto/manual commands";"VlvL";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\\Desk_1_Add_Ingredie";"De1_add_Ingredie.Oel_AutModLi";"1=Auto mode: Auto mode by linked or SFC";"Add_Ingredient";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\Val_Oil\\De1_Val_Oil";"De1_Val_Oil.AutModLi";"1=Auto mode: Auto mode by linked or SFC";"VlvL";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\Val_Oil\\De1_Val_Oil";"4.Out";"Output";"Or04";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\Val_Oil\\De1_Val_Oil";"De1_Val_Oil.FbkOpen";"1=Open: Feedback of Valve Opened";"VlvL";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\Val_Oil\\De1_Val_Oil";"3.Out";"Output";"Or04";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\Val_Oil\\De1_Val_Oil";"De1_Val_Oil.FbkClose";"1=Close: Feedback of Valve Closed";"VlvL";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\\Desk_1_Add_Ingredie";"De1_add_Ingredie.Oel_RstLi";"Linked reset signal";"Add_Ingredient";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\Val_Oil\\De1_Val_Oil";"De1_Val_Oil.RstLi";"Linked reset signal";"VlvL";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\\Desk_1_Add_Ingredie";"De1_add_Ingredie.QBA_EN";"BATCH enable";"Add_Ingredient";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\Val_Oil\\De1_Val_Oil";"De1_Val_Oil.BatchEn";"Enable remote operation of controller by Batch recipe";"VlvL";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\\Desk_1_Add_Ingredie";"De1_add_Ingredie.QBA_ID";"BATCH charge number";"Add_Ingredient";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\Val_Oil\\De1_Val_Oil";"De1_Val_Oil.BatchID";"Current Batch ID (number)";"VlvL";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\\Desk_1_Add_Ingredie";"De1_add_Ingredie.QBA_NA";"BATCH charge name";"Add_Ingredient";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\Val_Oil\\De1_Val_Oil";"De1_Val_Oil.BatchName";"Current Batch name";"VlvL";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\\Desk_1_Add_Ingredie";"De1_add_Ingredie.QSTEP_NO";"BATCH step number 32Bit";"Add_Ingredient";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\Val_Oil\\De1_Val_Oil";"De1_Val_Oil.StepNo";"Batch step number";"VlvL";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\Val_Pepper\\De1_Val_Pepper";"De1_Val_Pepper.Closed";"1=Valve is Closed";"VlvL";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\Val_Pepper\\De1_Val_Pepper";"3.In1";"Input 1";"Or04";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\Val_Pepper\\De1_Val_Pepper";"De1_Val_Pepper.Closing";"1=Valve is Closing";"VlvL";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\Val_Pepper\\De1_Val_Pepper";"3.In2";"Input 2";"Or04";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\Val_Pepper\\De1_Val_Pepper";"De1_Val_Pepper.Opened";"1=Valve is Open";"VlvL";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\Val_Pepper\\De1_Val_Pepper";"4.In1";"Input 1";"Or04";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\Val_Pepper\\De1_Val_Pepper";"De1_Val_Pepper.Opening";"1=Valve is Opening";"VlvL";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\Val_Pepper\\De1_Val_Pepper";"4.In2";"Input 2";"Or04";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\\Desk_1_Add_Ingredie";"De1_add_Ingredie.Pepper_OpenAut";"1=Open: Open Command in Auto Mode";"Add_Ingredient";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\Val_Pepper\\De1_Val_Pepper";"De1_Val_Pepper.OpenAut";"1=Open: Open Command in Auto Mode";"VlvL";
"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\\Desk_1_Add_Ingredie";"De1_add_Ingredie.Pepper_CloseAut";"1=Close: Close Command in Auto Mode";"Add_Ingredient";"Kitchen\Viewport_1\Desk_1\Add_Ingredients\Val_Pepper\\De1_Val_Pepper";"De1_Val_Pepper.CloseAut";"1=Close: Close Command in Auto Mode";"VlvL";
```

Comment: Show minimal code and a few lines of csv file that demonstrate the issue

Comment: The csv file is generated by software from Siemens. It contains lines with the following format: "plant\\chart\block.io1" , "plant\\chart\block3.io2", "plant\\chart2\block.io3", etc.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this - no problems reading such a csv file using simply `pd.read_csv('filename')`. Example: https://gist.github.com/northernocean/52e9fbf701a36aac65b23ac439c19630

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74826037/edit) the question with a [mcve]

Comment: Your stack trace gives this information: *Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 58, saw 3* How is line 58 different from the lines before it (lines1-57)? Can you provide a sample set of rows that reproduces the problem?

Comment: How do I add file to this post?

Comment: You will not be able to add files. You can paste some sample lines of text in your question (edit the question and add the extra detail).

Comment: Here is a test file:     https://mega.nz/file/V2QAyb6R#wnnkIWxgCBLiN3G-w8MuOASAszyAw_j43b9U-2TL7dA

Comment: I'm sorry I have no wish to click on links to sites I am not familiar with (I don't mean that this is not a legitimate site, just that I haven't seen it before so I have to be cautious). Please post your sample data in your question. This is the normal way at SO to create a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - you don't need to post the whole file or even all the data, simply enough to demonstrate the problem in such a way that others can reproduce the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is that your file is not a CSV file - a "***comma*** separated file", it is a CSV file - a "***semi-colon*** separated file". So if you tell pandas csv_reader to delimit the fields with a semi-colon, the results should be much better.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test2.csv", delimiter=';')
print(df.head())
```

Also, by the way, the reason you error in the original code on line 58 was because that was the first line with an actual comma in the line - all the other lines are read in as "one field" based on comma separated values, but this line gets split into more than one and then you have too many fields.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will try with the changes you mentioned. I do have some much bigger files than this to try. I will post if this solves it!

Answer (score 0):

With another file i got a "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 157936: invalid start byte" Error. The solution was to add file encoding cp1252 to the read_csv command

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
file_encoding = 'cp1252'

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Testmap\testfilelarge.csv', delimiter=';',encoding = file_encoding)
```